# How I can streaming video in Opera browser using UDP Multicast?

Tags: javascript, html, udp, video-streaming

I'm currently trying to display a video using `html5` using the `<video>` tag and its main options. I try to visualize a video streaming, in the following context: VLC emits streaming video using UDP multicast but no result.

However, I wish to display it in an `html` page on the `Opera` browser of Philips TV. Despite my searches on the internet I only found information to send from files or with `http` but not stream directly. I have already tried with different formats and plugin but in vain.

My question is therefore:
How to receive the streaming video with `udp`, and to read it thanks to the `<video>` tag in `html5` on my TV?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: i used axvlc web plugin for view the stream. but it works only for IE and Mozilla. I don't know the solution for opera. maybe you can use Axvlc for mozilla.